# Using custom class to handle database inquiries in AS3

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, class, urlvariables

I recently started delving into custom classes in AS3 (to hone my best-practices coding habits), and wanted to create a database class that allows a user to first instantiate a class that contains all the information necessary for methods within the class to add, delete, modify (etc) rows in a MySQL table (via PHP).  Of course, this involves using URLRequest, URLLoader and so forth.  My question is whether anyone as figured a way how to return data from a method specifically containing that var data without relying upon the method essentially dispatching an event (then having to create a listener rather than having that built into the class).  For example,

```
var myDB:dataBase = new dataBase("dbase","table","username","pword");

//this creates an instance of a database class with methods like:

trace(myDB.fetch(1)); //gets first row of table as a delimited string
```

OR

```
if (myDB.delete(1)) {} 
//returns Boolean true if delete of row 1 was successful
```

I found the answer below that contained a way to create a class that returns an event:

[Combining URLRequest, URLLoader and Complete Event Listener In Actionscript 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348615/combining-urlrequest-urlloader-and-complete-event-listener-in-actionscript-3-0)

but I want the method to return a string containing data from the database or a boolean confirmation, not to dispatch an event listener.  Here is an example of the class I made:

```
package com.customClasses {
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLVariables;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
    import fl.events.DataChangeEvent;
    import flash.events.Event

    public class dataBase {
        public var dbs:String = "";
        public var usr:String = "";
        public var pwd:String = "";
        public var tab:String = "";
        var returnData:String = "";

    // Constructor
    public function dataBase(dbs:String, usr:String, pwd:String, tab:String) {
        this.dbs = dbs;
        this.usr = usr;
        this.pwd = pwd;
        this.tab = tab;
    }

    public function fetch(idn:uint, par:String):String { 
        var returnData:String = "blank";
        var vUrlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("dBase.php");
        var vUrlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(); 

        function onLoadVarsComplete(event:Event): void {
            //retrieve success variable from our PHP script:
            if(event.target.data.msg == "success") {
                var rawData:URLVariables = new URLVariables( event.target.data );
                returnData = rawData.fromPHP;
            } else {
                returnData = "failed!";
            }
        }
        vUrlReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;    
        vUrlVars.dir=dbs; // name of table affected
        vUrlVars.alpha=usr; // username
        vUrlVars.beta=pwd;  // password
        vUrlVars.dbase=tab; // name of table affected
        vUrlVars.func="fetch"; // function for php script to use
        vUrlVars.idnum=idn; //if >0 search for record with that id
        vUrlReq.data = vUrlVars;
        var vLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader (vUrlReq);
        vLoader.addEventListener("complete", onLoadVarsComplete);
        vLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
        vLoader.load(vUrlReq);

        return (returnData);
    }
```

returnData returns "blank"... so I realize my method is not working as intended.  I also realize there my be some scope issues with the returnData string, and that I am using a nested function (probably a no-no).  Otherwise, any thoughts?

Comment: Of course you will get "blank" because you forgot that you have to wait for your "complete" event which is fired asynchronously.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you can use a callback function or a [`DataEvent`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/DataEvent.html) listener, like this :

**DB.as :**

```
package  {

    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    public class DB extends EventDispatcher {       

        public static const DATA_LOADED = 'data_loaded';

        public function DB() {
        }

        public function getDataUsingDataEvent(file_path:String):void {

            var url_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                url_loader.addEventListener(
                    Event.COMPLETE, 
                    function(e:Event):void
                    {
                        var event:DataEvent = new DataEvent(DATA_LOADED, true, false, url_loader.data);
                        dispatchEvent(event);
                    }
                )
                url_loader.load(new URLRequest(file_path));     
        }

        public function getDataUsingCallback(file_path:String, callback:Function):void {

            var url_loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
                url_loader.addEventListener(
                    Event.COMPLETE, 
                    function(e:Event):void 
                    {
                        callback(url_loader.data);
                    }
                )
                url_loader.load(new URLRequest(file_path));     
        }

    }

}
```

**And then :**

```
var db:DB = new DB();

    db.addEventListener(
        DB.DATA_LOADED, 
        function(event:DataEvent):void {
            trace(event.data);
        }
    )   
    db.getDataUsingDataEvent('file_path');

    db.getDataUsingCallback(
        'file_path', 
        function(data:String):void {
            trace(data);
        }
    )
```

Hope that can help.

Answer (score 1):

As you've stated it, this can't be done in AS3. You cannot wait for an asynchronous operation (such as `URLLoader/load()`) before returning the function and continuing script execution.

What you can do, if you'd prefer not to use `addEventListener()` so much, is pass through callbacks, or implement [method chaining](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_chaining) of [promises](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises). These patterns are not necessarily better than using events, and have their own problems, but let you write code that is arguably more readable as a sequence. These patterns are common in Javascript (which has the same asynchronous behavior as ActionScript), for example jQuery. Beware of ["callback hell"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) and "train wrecks". These techniques aim to make things simpler to write but sometimes make things more error prone.